# iOS persistence: storing and retrieving items in directory

Tags: ios, objective-c, persistence, nsfilemanager

I want to save a file to a folder, and then retrieve all the contents of that folder, so I do:

```
NSString *dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:storageFolder];
// StorageFolder is just a string like: "@"/FavoritesFolder"
// Filename is just a title given like "myTune.mp3"        
NSString *destinationString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",dataPath,filename];
  BOOL success = [object writeToFile:destinationString atomically:YES];
```

Then I want to retrieve the object, so I do

```
NSArray *dirContents = [[NSFileManager defaultManager]contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:dataPath error:nil];
```

But all I get an array of `filename` (like myTune.mp3). not the `Object` which is a NSDictionary. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Side note - don't use `stringWithFormat:` to build your path. Do this: `NSString *destinationString = [dataPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't strictly 'doing' anything wrong. It's your expectations that are wrong. The method you're using (`contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:`)

> Performs a shallow search of the specified directory and returns the paths of any contained items.

If you want to load the file back into memory you need to:

1. Decide which file you want
2. Get the full path to the file (directory path and file name)
3. Load the file (if it's a dictionary, `dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:`)

Comment: So if I want to get all items of a directory the best method is to use (contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:) And then myself write a method using the array to return a array of all objects in the directory?

Comment: Ok, so your goal is to get all of the dictionaries written into that directory back into memory. Then yes, you will need to iterate over them and load (as per the above) each dictionary.